# Llamar a un elemento de un array cuyo nombre del elemento se encuentra en una variable

Tags: javascript, array

Supongamos que tenemos lo siguiente:

en **data** tengo los valores **titulo, nombres, apellido**

y tengo un array con los siguientes elementos

**persona[0].titulo,
persona[0].nombres,
persona[0].apellido**

utilizo un **for** de la siguiente manera:

for (var a in data) {

}

como puedo utilizar el valor de **a** para hacer referencia al elemento del array cuyo nombre esta contenido en **a**

Muchas gracias, aprecio su ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 1):

En el ciclo que usa para iterar, puede acceder a cada uno de los atributos que tiene el elemento:

```
for (var a in data) {
  a.titulo;
  a.nombres;
  a.apellido;
}
```

La variable **a** toma el elemento del vector sobre el que se itera, por tanto esta se comporta como el objeto en cuestión [ Persona(titulo, nombres, apellido) ]

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var a in data) 
{
   console.log('Título: '+persona[a].titulo+ ', Nombre: '+persona[a].nombres+', persona[a].apellido');
}
```